# Should I say, "she puts the telephone down." or "she puts the receiver/handset down"?

Tags: word-choice, word-request, idiomatic-language

She tries to dial again, but still no answer. She puts the phone/receiver/handset down and leaves the room.

1) If using a landline phone, should I say "puts the phone down" or "puts the receiver/handset down"?

2) In American English what is more natural to use - receiver, handset, or something else maybe?

3) If she only puts down the receiver/handset and not the whole phone, where would you place "down"? After "puts" or after "phone/receiver/handset"?

Comment: Speaking of 'traditional' telephones, it would have been perfectly acceptable to say 'puts the phone down' even though it was actually only the receiver that was picked up.

Comment: Pretty much everybody I know of says "phone" when referring to the handset part of an old-timey phone in the context of communication. Saying "handset" is done when talking about it in technical sense (such as troubleshooting) to specifically exclude the base. Putting down the phone is correct, even if it's strictly technically speaking wrong